# Debugging a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure:

```
USE [OfficeAuto]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[INSERT_Project]    Script Date: 09/06/2011 10:42:44 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[INSERT_Project]
...
```

When I try to debug this, I cannot step past `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`.  The debugger just stops.  I thought I could step through a stored procedure just like through code in VS.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to debug the creation of the stored procedure or the execution of the proc? To handle the latter, you'd need to highlight EXEC dbo.Insert_project and hit the debug button

Answer (score 1):

OTOH, I'd remove some of the `GO` because the use of `GO` is a batch terminator, which signifies the *end* of a command. (Indicates the end of a batch of SQL statements).
As I see it, this should work fine:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[INSERT_Project]
...
```

Also worth noting that `GO` is not a T-SQL command, rather use `BEGIN` and `END`.